# Printing all the lines that contain a certain word exactly k times

Tags: linux, shell

I have to search for all the lines from a file which contain a given word exactly k times. I think that I should use grep/sed/awk but I don't know how. My idea was to check every line by line using `sed` and `grep` like this:

```
line=1
while [ (sed -n -'($line)p' $name) -n ]; do
    if [ (sed -n -'($line)p' $name | grep -w -c $word) -eq "$number" ]; then
        sed -n -'($line)p' $name
    fi
    let line+=1
done
```

My first problem is that I get the following error : `syntax error near unexpected token 'sed'`. Then I realize that for my test file the command `sed -n -'p1' test.txt | grep -w -c "ab"` doesn't return the exact number of apparitions of "ab" in the first line from my file (it returns 1 but there are 3 apparitions).
My `test.txt` file:

```
abc ab cds ab abcd edfs ab
kkmd ab jnabc bad ab
abcdefghijklmnop ab cdab ab ab
abcde bad abc cdef a b
```

Comment: You don't need to loop over the file when you use `sed` or `awk`. It's what these languages do internally anyway.

Comment: @pfnuesel i know but i didn't know other way to check line by line

Comment: That's what `sed` does, checking line by line.

Comment: See for an answer using `grep`. It could also be achieved with a one-liner in `sed` or `awk`. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'\\<ab\\>' -v count=2 'NF==count+1' file   

kkmd ab jnabc bad ab
```

note that `\<` and `\>` word boundaries might be `gawk` specific.

for variable assignment, I think easiest will be

```
$ word=ab; awk -F"\\\<$word\\\>" -v count=2 'NF==count+1' file 

kkmd ab jnabc bad ab
```

Comment: I introduce your command in my shell script and it doesn't print that line

Comment: @karakfa how can i replace that ab with an `$word` variable ?

Comment: Actually, `\<` and `\>` are not just `gawk` specific, they were added to GNU grep for compatibility with SVR4. The grep manual also notes that they're not "standard" and should be avoided.  If Gawk has included them, it's a nod to GNU grep which is a nod to SVR4. The "character class" word delimiters of `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` don't appear to work for me.

Comment: @karakfa that `awk -F"\\\<$word\\\>" -v count=2 'NF==count+1' file` gives me an error `awk: warning: escape sequence `\<' treated as plain `<'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\>' treated as plain `>'`

Comment: are you sure you have 3 backslashes?  What is your awk version?  Also try replacing `<` and `>` with the letter `y`

Comment: Well done; I think this is probably neatest.  Note that the BSD (Mac OS X) version version of `awk` does not support the `\<` and `\>` word boundary markers (so running this script on the data file produces no output).  It works fine with GNU `awk`, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use grep, but you'd have to use it twice. (You can't use a single grep because ERE has no way to negate a string, you can only negate a bracket expression, which will match single characters.)

The following is tested with GNU grep v2.5.1, where you can use `\<` and `\>` as (possibly non-portable) word delimiters:

```
$ word="ab"
$ < input.txt egrep "(\<$word\>.*){3}" | egrep -v "(\<$word\>.*){4}"
abc ab cds ab abcd edfs ab
abcdefghijklmnop ab cdab ab ab
$ < input.txt egrep "(\<$word\>.*){2}" | egrep -v "(\<$word\>.*){3}"
kkmd ab jnabc bad ab
```

The idea here is that we'll extract from our input file lines with N occurrences of the word, then strip from that result any lines with N+1 occurrences.  Lines with fewer than N occurrences of course won't be matched by the first grep.

---

Or, you might also do this in pure bash, if you're feeling slightly masochistic:

```
$ word="ab"; num=3
$ readarray lines < input.txt
$ for this in "${lines[@]}"; do declare -A words=(); x=( $this ); for y in "${x[@]}"; do ((words[$y]++)); done; [ "0${words[$word]}" -eq "$num" ] && echo "$this"; done
abc ab cds ab abcd edfs ab

abcdefghijklmnop ab cdab ab ab
```

Broken out for easier reading (or scripting):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Salt to taste
word="ab"; num=3

# Pull content into an array. This isn't strictly necessary, but I like
# getting my file IO over with quickly if possible.
readarray lines < input.txt

# Walk through the array (or you could just walk through the input file)
for this in "${lines[@]}"; do

  # Initialize this line's counter array
  declare -A words=()

  # Break up the words into array elements
  x=( $this )

  # Step though the array, counting each unique word
  for y in "${x[@]}"; do
    ((words[$y]++))
  done

  # Check the count for "our" word
  [ "0${words[$word]}" -eq $num ] && echo "$this"

done
```

Wasn't that fun?  :)

---

But this `awk` option makes the most sense to me. It's a portable one-liner that doesn't depend on GNU awk (so it'll work in OS X, BSD, etc.)

```
awk -v word="ab" -v num=3 '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){a[$i]++}} a[word]==num; {delete a}' input.txt
```

This works by building an associative array to count the words on each line, then printing the line if the count for the "interesting" word is what's specified as `num`.  It's the same basic concept as the bash script above, but awk lets us do this so much better. :)

Comment: Don't know why but for the first example it's printing `abcdefghijklmnop ab cdab ab ab`. Same question here, how i can change it to work with variables ?

Comment: @ghoti That looks like a common theme for the answers here - currently three answers, all at -1...

Comment: @gamamen2, this answer already is compatible with a `$word` variable. Can you perhaps help me understand what it's missing for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with grep

```
grep -E "(${word}.*){${number}}" test.txt
```

This looks for `${number}` occurrences of `${word}` per line. The wildcard `.*` is needed since we also want to match occurrences where matches of `${word}` are not next to each other.

Here's what I do:

```
$ echo 'abc ab cds ab abcd edfs ab
kkmd ab jnabc bad ab
abcdefghijklmnop ab cdab ab ab
abcde bad abc cdef a b' > test.txt

$ word=abc
$ number=2

$ grep -E "(${word}.*){${number}}" test.txt
> abc ab cds ab abcd edfs ab
> abcde bad abc cdef a b
```

Comment: I tried with `grep -E "(${word}.*){${number})" ./$name` and it doesn't work.

Comment: What's `$name`? You have to add the file you want to `grep`. See my updated answer. If `$name` is the name of your file, can you be more explicit on what didn't work?

Comment: $name is the file name, this should work for any text file. And when i said that it didn't work i wanted to tell that it didn't print the lines.

Comment: I updated my answer with step by step instructions what I do. It works for me. What system are you on?

Comment: i changed `./$name` with `$name` and it partially work, i mean for word = ab and number = 2 it will show this line too `kkmd ab jnabc bad ab`. I'm using Kubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Oh, I only realize now that you want **exactly** k occurrences of `${word}`. Then, I'm afraid, `grep` is not the right tool. But the `awk` solution should work.

Comment: I might be tempted to use `grep -E "(${word}.*){${number}}" test.txt | grep -vE "(${word}.*){$((${number} + 1))}"` (count the number of lines with N or more occurrences, and then reject the lines with more than N occurrences.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, very wise of you to put that in a comment rather than an answer. I earned a downvote for it!  :-D

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. I'd opt for the `awk` solution, rather than `grep`. It's short and clear.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use `sed`.  If you are looking for character sequences, you can use code like this.  However, it doesn't distinguish between the word on its own and the word embedded in another word (so it treats `ab` and `abc` as both containing `ab`).

```
word="ab"
number=2

sed -n -e "/\($word.*\)\{$(($number + 1))\}/d" -e "/\($word.*\)\{$number\}/p" test.txt
```

- By default, nothing is printed (`-n`).
- The first `-e` expression looks for 3 (or more) occurrences of `$word` and deletes lines containing them (and skips to the next line of input).  The `$(($number + 1))` is [shell arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion).
- The second `-e` expressions looks for 2 occurrences of `$word` (there won't be more) and prints the lines that match.

If you want words on their own, then you have to work a lot harder.  You'd need extended regular expressions, triggered with the `-E` option on BSD (Mac OS X), or `-r` with GNU `sed`.

```
number=2
plus1=$(($number + 1))
word=ab
sed -En -e "/(^|[^[:alnum:]])($word([^[:alnum:]]).*){$plus1}/d" \
        -e "/(^|[^[:alnum:]])($word([^[:alnum:]]).*){$number}$word$/d" \
        -e "/(^|[^[:alnum:]])($word([^[:alnum:]]|$).*){$number}/p" test.txt
```

This is similar to the previous version, but it has considerably more delicate word handling.

- The unit `(^|[^[:alnum:]])` looks for either the start of line or a non-alphanumeric character (change `alnum` to `alpha` throughout if you don't want digits to stop matches).
- The first `-e` looks for start of line or a non-alphanumeric character, followed by the word and a non-alphanumeric and zero or more other characters, N+1 times, and deletes such lines (skipping to the next line of input).
- The second `-e` looks for start of line or a non-alphanumeric character, followed by the word and a non-alphanumeric and zero or more other characters N times, and then the word again followed by end of line, and deletes such lines.
- The third `-e` looks for start of line or a non-alphanumeric character, followed by the word and a non-alphanumeric and zero or more other characters N times and prints such lines.

Given the (extended) input file:

```
abc  NO  ab cds ab abcd edfs ab
kkmd YES ab jnabc bad ab
abcd NO  efghijklmnop ab cdab ab ab
abcd NO  efghijklmnop ab cdab ab  ab
abcd NO  e bad abc cdef a b
ab   YES abcd abcd ab
best YES ab ab candidly
best YES ab  ab candidly
ab   NO  abcd abcd ab ab
hope NO  abcd abcd ab ab ab
nope NO  abcd abcd ab ab  ab
ab   YES abcd abcd ab not bad
said YES ab not so bad ab or bad
```

Example output:

```
kkmd YES ab jnabc bad ab
ab   YES abcd abcd ab
best YES ab ab candidly
best YES ab  ab candidly
ab   YES abcd abcd ab not bad
said YES ab not so bad ab or bad
```

It is not a trivial exercise in `sed`.  It would be simpler if you could rely on word-boundary detection.  For example, in Perl:

```
number=2
plus1=$(($number + 1))
word=ab
perl -n -e "next  if /(\b$word\b.*?){$plus1}/;
            print if /(\b$word\b.*?){$number}/" test.txt
```

This produces the same output as the `sed` script, but is a lot simpler because of the `\b` word boundary detection (the `.*?` non-greedy matching isn't crucial to the operation of the script).